# I was wondering if it is possible to create one arraylist for two different listviews across different activities in android studio?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

This is the activity where i add my person objects into the arraylist and i was planning on bringing over the same arraylist to another activity(editList.java) to display the same listview but i am not sure how.  I've researched on this topic but there is only help on how to put multiple arraylist into one listview. Please note i am quite new to android programming

people.java

```
public class people extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnAdd;
Button btnDelete;
ListView lvPeople;


ArrayList<person> alPeople = new ArrayList<person>();
ArrayAdapter<person> aaPeople;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_people);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    lvPeople = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPeople);


    aaPeople = new ArrayAdapter<person>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alPeople);
    lvPeople.setAdapter(aaPeople);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View viewDialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_dialog, null);
            final EditText etName = (EditText) viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.etName);
            final EditText etAge = (EditText) viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.etAge);
            final DatePicker dpBirthdate = (DatePicker) viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.dpBirthdate);
            AlertDialog.Builder myBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(people.this);

            myBuilder.setView(viewDialog);
            myBuilder.setTitle("Add person to list");

            myBuilder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String name = etName.getText().toString();
                    String age = etAge.getText().toString();
                    int dpBirthdateDay = dpBirthdate.getDayOfMonth();
                    int dpBirthdateMonth = dpBirthdate.getMonth() + 1;
                    int dpBirthdateYear = dpBirthdate.getYear();

                    String birthday = Integer.toString(dpBirthdateDay) + "/" + Integer.toString(dpBirthdateMonth) + "/" + Integer.toString(dpBirthdateYear);
                    person person = new person();
                    person.setName(name);
                    person.setAge(age);
                    person.setExtbirthday(birthday);
                    person.setBirthday(Integer.toString(dpBirthdateDay));
                    person.setBirthmonth(Integer.toString(dpBirthdateMonth));
                    person.setBirthyear(Integer.toString(dpBirthdateYear));

                    alPeople.add(person);
                    aaPeople.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(people.this, "Person Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });
            AlertDialog myDialog = myBuilder.create();
            myDialog.show();
        }
    });


    //this is code for list view item click
    int personPos = 0;
    lvPeople.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View viewDialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_dialog, null);
            final TextView tvName = (TextView) viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            final TextView tvAge = (TextView) viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvAge);
            final TextView tvBirthdate = (TextView) viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.tvBirthdate);
            AlertDialog.Builder myBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(people.this);

            myBuilder.setView(viewDialog);
            myBuilder.setTitle("Person Info");

            int personPos = position;
            tvName.setText(alPeople.get(personPos).getName());
            tvAge.setText(alPeople.get(personPos).getAge());
            tvBirthdate.setText(alPeople.get(personPos).getExtbirthday());

            myBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            AlertDialog myDialog = myBuilder.create();
            myDialog.show();
        }
    });
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View viewDialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.delete_dialog, null);
            final EditText etIndex = (EditText) viewDialog.findViewById(R.id.etIndex);

            AlertDialog.Builder myBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(people.this);

            myBuilder.setView(viewDialog);
            myBuilder.setTitle("Delete Person");


            myBuilder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(etIndex.getText().toString());
                    if (alPeople.size() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(people.this, "There is nothing to delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        alPeople.remove(index - 1);

                        aaPeople.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }
            });
            myBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            AlertDialog myDialog = myBuilder.create();
            myDialog.show();
        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an `ArrayList` of data to an `Activity` you start via an `Intent` if the type of objects in the `ArrayList` implements the `Parcelable` interface - see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra(java.lang.String%2C%20java.util.ArrayList%3C%3F%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E)).

If this is not an option, you may be able to generate an `ArrayList` based on some kind of identifier for each of the objects in the original `ArrayList`, say perhaps a `String` identifier - see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra(java.lang.String%2C%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)). In this case, if you need to display the model data again in the activity you start, you will need to load it using the identifiers first.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class, say **NewArray extends ListView** and copy the code of your **ListView** in this class.

Create instance of **NewArray** wherever you want to use this **ListView**